# Why the code is not considering some of the assets as prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have prefabs assets with the blue box symbol : The code consider this as prefabs and make the changes to them :

[image: Prefabs]

And this are prefabs I created by dragging them to the Assets :

[image: My prefabs]

This code will add a Rigidbody to the prefabs in the first screenshot but it will not add Rigidbody to the two prefabs in the second screenshot :

```
using Packages.Rider.Editor.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddComponents : Editor
{
    private static string GetClickedDirFullPath()
    {
        string clickedAssetGuid = Selection.assetGUIDs[0];
        string clickedPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(clickedAssetGuid);
        string clickedPathFull = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), clickedPath);

        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(clickedPathFull);
        return attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) ? clickedPathFull : Path.GetDirectoryName(clickedPathFull);
    }

    private static string GetPath()
    {
        string path = GetClickedDirFullPath();
        int index = path.IndexOf("Assets");
        string result = path.Substring(index);

        return result;
    }

    static List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    [MenuItem("Assets/Get Prefabs")]
    private static void GetFolders()
    {        
        string selectedPath = GetPath();

        string[] assetsPaths = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths();

        foreach (string assetPath in assetsPaths)
        {
            if (assetPath.Contains(selectedPath))
            {
                if (assetPath.Contains("Prefabs"))
                {
                    paths.Add(assetPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    [MenuItem("Assets/Get Prefabs")]
    public static void GetPrefabs()
    {
        GetFolders();

        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count; i++)
        {
            if (File.Exists(paths[i]))
            {
                if (paths[i].Contains(".prefab"))
                {
                    GameObject contentsRoot = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(paths[i]);

                    if (contentsRoot.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)
                    {
                        // Modify Prefab contents.
                        contentsRoot.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

                        // Save contents back to Prefab Asset and unload contents.
                        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(contentsRoot, paths[i]);
                        PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(contentsRoot);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not "Prefabs" but they are imported "Models" ... they are pretty similar but "Prefabs" are only those you actually create as Prefabs in Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why am I doing this script ?

The reason is that if I have for example 300 different prefabs of effects that I want to make from them bullets, it's a part of a package I bought. The problem is that the prefabs are located in too many folders and sub folders and to make them bullets at least in my case I wanted to add to each one of them a Rigidbody to test them. I did a backup for the original prefabs or I can download them again or add some undo options. but the idea is clear why I did the script. Maybe there is a better/easier/shorter way/s to do it but it's working.

This is a working solution script :

What have I changed : Maybe I could make it all easier and shorter but it's working !

- Instead Contains I'm using now EndsWith :

  if (paths[i].EndsWith(".prefab"))
- Added a local variable to get the Rigidbody and then checking if it's null and not if it's not null : if it's null that's mean there is no Rigidbody component attached to it and I checked if it's not null != and since the other prefabs in the first screenshot already had Rigidbody it didn't add to them a Rigidbody it's was not null. So the main problem was to switch from != nukk to == null

  var rb = contentsRoot.GetComponent();
    if (rb == null)

The full script :

```
using Packages.Rider.Editor.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddComponents : Editor
{
    private static string GetClickedDirFullPath()
    {
        string clickedAssetGuid = Selection.assetGUIDs[0];
        string clickedPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(clickedAssetGuid);
        string clickedPathFull = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), clickedPath);

        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(clickedPathFull);
        return attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) ? clickedPathFull : Path.GetDirectoryName(clickedPathFull);
    }

    private static string GetPath()
    {
        string path = GetClickedDirFullPath();
        int index = path.IndexOf("Assets");
        string result = path.Substring(index);

        return result;
    }

    static List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    [MenuItem("Assets/Get Prefabs")]
    private static void GetFolders()
    {
        string selectedPath = GetPath();
        string[] assetsPaths = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths();

        foreach (string assetPath in assetsPaths)
        {
            if (assetPath.Contains(selectedPath))
            {
                if (assetPath.Contains("Prefabs"))
                {
                    paths.Add(assetPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("Assets/Get Prefabs")]
    public static void GetPrefabs()
    {
        GetFolders();

        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count; i++)
        {
            if (File.Exists(paths[i]))
            {
                if (paths[i].EndsWith(".prefab"))
                {
                    GameObject contentsRoot = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(paths[i]);

                    var rb = contentsRoot.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                    if (rb == null)
                    {
                        // Modify Prefab contents.
                        contentsRoot.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

                        // Save contents back to Prefab Asset and unload contents.
                        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(contentsRoot, paths[i]);
                        PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(contentsRoot);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```